# Update variables in array

Tags: php

I have a simple array `$arr` which contains 6 numbers.

```
$arr=[10,24,33,47,58,65];
```

I want to assign each number to a variable prefixed `$color` so `$color1`, `$color2` etc up to `$color6`

This then gives `$color1` a value of 10, `$color2` a value of 24 etc

Then I want to print each of them out e.g. `echo $color1;` `echo $color2;` etc

This is what I'm trying but it doesn't work, is there a better way?

```
$i=1;

foreach($arr as $row)
{
    $color.$i = implode(",",$row);
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for something aptly named [variable-variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). To achieve this, you'll need to do:

```
<?php
    $i=1;
    foreach($arr as $row) {
        ${"color" . $i} = implode(",",$row);
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

And now you can `echo $color1;`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much, thanks for the link too, a new one on me!

Comment: No worries, I wouldn't advise using them mind as they can lead to a lot of confusion later on. A similar thing occurs when using the `extract` function, if you use an IDE it won't be able to find these variables - but they do remain useful! :) also, if this answer has worked for you, could you press the big tick next to it?

Comment: Its for a back up info gathering operation so not in production as such, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just make them as keys and access it as `echo $new_arr['color1'];`,`echo $new_arr['color2'];`.... so on ?

```
<?php
$arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as &$val)
{
    $new_arr["color$val"] = $val;
}
print_r($new_arr);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [color1] => 1
    [color2] => 2
    [color3] => 3
    [color4] => 4
    [color5] => 5
    [color6] => 6
)
```

Comment: +1 definitely a use case for an array of related values imho.

Answer (score 1):

The next code will work:

```
$arr = array(10,24,33,47,58,65);
$i=1;

foreach($arr as $row)
{
    $temp = 'color' . $i;
    $$temp = $row; // mention the double $ sign. It will create a variable variable 
    $i++;
}

echo $color1;
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/fet-sty

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative approach, there's a succinct way to achieve something similar using [`extract()`](https://www.php.net/extract) with the caveat that your variables will be zero-indexed and contain an underscore; e.g: `$color_0`, `$color_1` etc.

```
$arr = [10, 24, 33, 47, 58, 65];
extract($arr, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'color');

var_dump($color_0, $color_1, $color_2, $color_3, $color_4, $color_5);
```

Yields:

```
int 10
int 24
int 33
int 47
int 58
int 65
```

You can enforce variable naming from one by modifying `$arr` slightly to enforce an index from one, like so:

```
$arr = [1 => 10, 24, 33, 47, 58, 65];
```

This creates variables named `$color_1`, `$color_2` etc.

Hope this helps :)

**Edit**

I just noticed above, @James' point above is worth noting - a downside of this approach is that you can extract `n` number of 'invisible' variables into your program's scope. which isn't always a good thing, especially when you have to debug with `var_dump(get_defined_vars())`. `extract` can be quite useful though, for instance if you have a simple templating rendering system.